# Переписать элементы главной диагонали в одномерный массив

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
A = []
for i in range(2):
    A.append([0] * 3)
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[i])):
        A[i][j] = int(input("Введите значение: "))
        print(A)
```

Как переписать элементы главной диагонали из двумерного массива в одномерный массив?

Comment: 1) Выяснить что такое главная диагональ матрицы. 2) Пройтись по этой главной диагонали вашего двумерного массива (способ прохода вы уже знаете, ибо все необходимые команды вы уже используете в вашем коде). 3) Во время прохода добавлять элементы в новый массив (и опять, всё нужное для этого уже есть в вашем коде).

Comment: Вариант для гиков - `D = sum(A,[])[::len(A[0])+1]`. :)